# How can I read text in front of a print! message?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, stdout, stdin, println

I'm trying to make a program that reads any word on the command line and prints it on a new line that's all, what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
Some text: hello
```

But instead I get something like this:

```
Some text:
Hello
```

Since using `print!` instead of `println!` the phrase "some text" is not printed.

What's going on?

```
fn main() {
    loop {
        let mut linea = String::new();
        print!("something:\t");
        let ingreso = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut linea).unwrap();
        println!("{:?}",ingreso);
        if linea == "exit".to_string(){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print!` does not flush stdout. You need to import the `std::io::Write` trait and call `std::io::stdout().flush()`.

Also, the return value from `read_line` returns how many bytes where read. If you want to print the text that was entered, print the `linea` variable.